# How to allow Oracle Cloud instances to access only Oracle Autonomous Database?

Tags: oracle-cloud-infrastructure, oracle-autonomous-db

I use Oracle Compute instances and Oracle Autonomous Database (ATP).

I want to allow compute instances to access only Autonomous Databases and I don't want to allow compute instances access to other public network.

I tried to set up an egress rule by security lists, but Autonomous Database's ip address is subject to change.
I think this approach is inappropriate.

My license is Oracle Cloud Infrastructure Free Tier.
So, I can't use Private Endpoint Access to Autonomous Database.

Do you have a solution to allow compute instances to access only Autonomous Databases?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Service Gateway on your VCN and remove NAT/IGW. This way the VCN will only be connected to OCI services, which includes Autonomous.

https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/paas/autonomous-database/adbsa/access-service-gateway.html#GUID-76D412D4-03F4-49BA-B70C-DEA70B11AC34